# Fibonacci sieve and factoring

Tags: reference-request, fibonacci-numbers, sieve-theory

I want to know different sieve techniques for Fibonacci numbers and how they works. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Other_identities) it is written only that the Cassinie's identity are useful in setting up the special number field sieve to factorize Fibonacci numbers, but, it is not explained how people use it to factorize Fibonacci numbers.

I already have searched for sieve method for Fibonacci numbers, but found nowhere. Can anyone explain it please or give link, where I can find it ?

Any new idea that can help in Fibonacci sieving is also welcome.

Comment: [This link](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/pari-gp/ggnfs/Linux/src/lasieve4/INSTALL.and.USE) may be useful, it was in the Wiki page you have linked.

Comment: Anyone ? Please..